# Get value from QJsonObject by index

Tags: c++, json, qt, qjson, qjsonobject

In my app I use `json` object to get result from remote database. Usually response string looks like:

```js
{
    status:"ok",
    data: [
        { field1:"value1", field2:"value2", field3:"value3" },
        { field1:"value4", field2:"value5", field3:"value6" },
        { field1:"value7", field2:"value8", field3:"value9" }
    ]
}
```

It looks good and I can get value from speciified row/col by:

```cpp
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());
QJsonObject responseObject = jsonResponse.object();
if(responseObject.value("status").toString() == "ok") {
     QJsonArray dataObject = responseObject.value("data").toArray();
     // and here I can get the value, for example 2-nd row, field2
     QString value = dataObject.at(1).toObject().value("field2").toString(); 
}
```

But sometimes I need to get the value not by name but by index. Ok, I do following:

```cpp
QJsonObject obj = dataObject.at(1).toObject();
QString key = obj.keys().at(1); // I use index here instead of name
QString value = obj.value(key).toString();
```

But unfortunately it looks that `keys()` not preserves field order so key with index 0 not exactly will be first field in its `QJsonObject`.

So my question - how can I get appropriate field from `QJsonObject` by index and not by name only?

Answer (score 5):

first suggestion :
    maybe you can use this code instead, which is more readable

```
responseObject["status"].toString() == "ok"
```

and here is your question suggestion

maybe you can try iterator, the below code just the example:

```
QJsonArray dataObject = responseObject["data"].toArray();
QJsonArray::iterator it;
for (it = dataObject.begin(); it != dataObject.end(); it++) {
    QString key = it->first;
    QString value = it->second;
}
```